# when i resize big tiff image to less than 25% ( say 17% ), the pixels are wrapped from left to right

Tags: resize, imagemagick, word-wrap

im using image magick v7.16.0. i have a very big image of size 440*1700. i want this to be resized to 17% of the original Size.
I tried with Resize, Scale and Rescale methods with intended width/height parameters and also with MagicGeometry.
But the resized image wraps the pixels from left side to right side.[Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXt4D.png)

Can any one help me in understanding why this wrapping is seen ?
This wrapping is seen only when i resize to less than 25%. [ when i resize to 50% or 80% i dont see this wrapping ]

Comment: What is your exact Imagemagick version - what does it tell you when you do `magick -version`? What was your exact command line?  An image of 400x1700 pixels is not very big? Post a link to the original image.

Comment: as mentioned i am using v7.16.0. Im not using commandlne.. im using package from NuGet Package manager. I create instance of 
obj = new MagickImage( path of the tiff ) // get new instance

afte this i try to resize ( i tried with both width / height and magicGeometry )

obj.resize( parameter )

here the resized image has wrapping of pixels from right to left.

Comment: There is no version 7.16.0 of Imagemagick. Please post your full commands as text in your Question, not in the comments. They are not very readable there. I suspect you may have an issue with your other software (NuGet?) or your syntax. Also please find your proper version of Imagemagick. The current version is 7.0.10.6.

Comment: i dont used command. i got Software from NuGet package manager.

Comment: Test with Imagemagick command line. If it fails, then there is a problem with the install of Imagemagick. If it works, then the issue is with your NuGet package or your syntax.